# Xamarin: Testing Android application using Moq/NUnit and the MockContext?

Tags: c#, android, nunit, xamarin.android, moq

I am trying to set up some tests for some existing code and need to be able to mock things like `ViewFlipper.FindViewById`.

So far to do this I have had to create a mockable wrapper for the `ViewFlipper`. Now the issue I have is that I want to return a mocked view. The mocked view needs to have a Context passed into it's ctor. I have found the `MockableContext` class in the `Java.Test` namespace but it doesn't seem to like being newed up? I get null ref exceptions?

Should I be able to use this class in this manner? Is there another way to do this? Simply creating a new `Mock<Context>` doesn't work either :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Android.App.Application.Context](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P:Android.App.Application.Context) property which I believe is equivalent to the [Android.Content.Context.ApplicationContext](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P:Android.Content.Context.ApplicationContext) property, except that it's static and available everywhere.

I came across it in this Stack Overflow answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19248475/1071320

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the test units running as a .NET assembly which simply does not exist within the "Context" (pun intended), of Android.

Examination of Android.App.Application.Context will result in the same exception.

Android.Test.Mock.MockContext is a wrapper around Java code and when running a unit test, the assembly is running in a Windows environment, not a Java environment.

It would be nice to be able to unit test a Xamarin view... but I am uncertain that it is possible to mock the Android context that is required.