# Reading an asset in a Xamarin NUnit test class

Tags: nunit, xamarin.android, android-testing

I want to read a mock RSS feed file to test against in a Xamarin NUnit test for an Android app. The test class has no context so I can't put the file in the Assets folder and do this:

```
System.IO.Stream strIn = instanceOfAssetManager.Open(feedFile);
```

It also has no ancestor, so I can't do this:

```
System.IO.Stream strIn = this.Class.ClassLoader.ResourceAsStream(feedFile);
```

Any suggestions how I can get to the jolly thing?

This case solved a similar problem for a different platform/setup:
[Storing test files in the test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547783/storing-test-files-in-the-test-project)

Comment: Have you tried to let the test class derived from `Android.Test.InstrumentationTestRunner` and then call `TargetContext.Resources.Assets.Open("feedFile)`?

Comment: @Aaron my test app bombs out with a "Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError" when I derive from `Android.Test.InstrumentationTestRunner`. It looks like it is not compatible with NUnitLite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The test class has no context so I can't put the file in the Assets folder and do this:

Is there a reason you need to use Android Assets? Using [.NET Embedded Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950960.aspx) by setting the file's **Build action**  to `EmbeddedResource` permits greater portability -- it's present on all .NET platforms -- and neatly sidesteps the Android Context issue.

If you need to use Android Assets, then you can use the [Android.App.Application.Context](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.App.Application.Context) property, which is equivalent to the [Context.ApplicationContext](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.Content.Context.ApplicationContext) property, except static and available everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, Jon. I have set the build action to `EmbeddedResource`, but I am tripping over the syntax. I can see that the following file is created: `../obj/Debug/SpotlightTests.Assets.appfeed.xml`, but if I try to read it with `Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.Assets.Open()` as either just `appfeed.xml` or with the path-dotted syntax as the MS docs says `SpotlightTests.Assets.appfeed.xml` I get a FileNotFound exception.

Comment: If you use `EmbeddedResource`, you need to use [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx), e.g. `typeof(Something).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("name")`.

Answer (score 0):

Check properties of the file. I had to set "Build Action" to AndroidAsset and than you can use `instanceOfAssetManager.Open(feedFile);`